# Get style attribute value add 'X' and set the new value

Tags: javascript, jquery

when user clicks on the load-more button and card-wrapper has class list-view.

I wanted to get the mason style attr value and add 300px on top of it and set that value to mason div.

Issue here is i can get the mason arrt value, but newheight is returning "NaN".

Please help!!

```js
$('.load-more').on('click', function() {

    if ($('.cards-wrapper').hasClass('list-view')) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            var currentHeight = $('.mason').attr('style');
            console.log('current' + currentHeight);

            var newHeight = parseInt(currentHeight);
            console.log('new height' + newHeight);
            $('.mason').css('height', newHeight + 300);

        }, 3000);

    }
});
```

```html
<div class="mason clear-fix" style="height: 6380px;">
```

Comment: why are you reading style???? read the height! http://api.jquery.com/height/ or css("height")

Comment: currentHeight = $('.mason').attr('style') ?? That is not the height

Comment: height or innerHeight value is not same a mason style height value so i need to get the arrt value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this. It's working.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.load-more').on('click', function() {

    

        setTimeout(function() {
            var currentHeight = jQuery('.mason')[0].style.height;
            console.log('current' + currentHeight);

            var newHeight = parseInt(currentHeight);
            console.log('new height' + newHeight);
            jQuery('.mason').css('height', newHeight + 300);

        }, 3000);

   
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mason clear-fix" style="height: 6380px;">

<button class="load-more"></button>
```

I have just used `jQuery('.mason')[0].style.height;` to get height value from style attribute. I hope this will work for you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Get height from `.mason` element, not attribute style.

`var currentHeight = $('.mason').height();`

Comment: I tried with both height & innerHeight these values are not equal to mason style attribute  values

Answer (score 0):

You could use either `$('.mason').height()` or `$('.mason').css("height")` to get the height of the element, same goes for setting the new height of the element

```js
$('.load-more').on('click', function() {


  setTimeout(function() {
    var currentHeight = $('.mason').height();
    console.log('current ' + currentHeight);

    var newHeight = parseInt(currentHeight);
    console.log('new height ' + (newHeight + 300));
    $('.mason').height((newHeight + 300));

  }, 3000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="load-more">load more</div>
<div class="mason clear-fix" style="height: 6380px;">
```

Comment: this value is not same as mason style attr value      var currentHeight = $('.mason').height();

Comment: this is because data is loading from other service so i cant user height or innerheight

Comment: @ArunKumar have you tried `$('.mason').css("height")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method jQuery's `height()` in order to get/set the height of the div, please see following example:

```js
$('.load-more').on('click', function() {

   setTimeout(function() {
        var currentHeight = $('.mason').height()
        console.log('current' + currentHeight);

        var newHeight = parseInt(currentHeight) + 300;
        console.log('new height' + newHeight);
        $('.mason').height(newHeight + 300);

    }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.mason {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mason clear-fix" style="height: 100px;">
</div>
<input type="button" class="load-more" value="expand">
```

**Note**: You're also showing `currentHeight` in console instead of the new one:

```
var newHeight = parseInt(currentHeight);
console.log('new height' + newHeight);
```

The above code prints the currentHeight, you should do something like:

```
var newHeight = parseInt(currentHeight) + 300;
console.log('new height' + newHeight);
```

I hope it helps you, bye.